# Java Date Calculation

Tags: java, date

I have a database field where date is stored as DD/MM/YYYY format. Now what I want to do is to see if today date = stored date - 1. Basically if today is the day before the end date. Based on that I will do some action...

example of format:

```
10/02/2012
```

There is formatting issue here because am using this:

```
Date todayDate;
```

And the stored date is VARCHAR2 in DB. Am assuming I would have to convert the retrieved date to Date regular format, or something like that. Help would be appreciated.

Update:

```
                currentEndDate =  rset.getString("ENDDATE");
                endDate = (Date)formatter.parse(currentEndDate);
                /*Check if end date = today date - 1*/
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                //set to end date
                cal.setTime(endDate);
                //end date - 1
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 
                Date today;
```

Now this is what I have..I am trying here to get the end date -1 so I did that using add() function. Now How can I check if end-date - 1 == today date or not? because when I tried :

```
if(today.equals(cal.add(Calendar.date, -1)))
```

it said void return from the add function. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn the String into a date.  You can do this in your query or after you get the string result:

Option 1: turn it into a Date type in your query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE("COLNAME", 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM "MYTABLE"
```

Option 2: turn it into a Date type after you get the string:

```
String date_from_db;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(date_from_db);
```

Then you can see if the current time (`new Date()`) is between the retrieved date and a day before that.  If you want to handle all corner cases including leap seconds, you'll have to use a `Calendar`, but if you're okay with leaving out leap seconds then it'll be fine to just subtract 24*60*60*1000 milliseconds from your db date.

You can't directly compare a `Date` and a `Calendar` as per the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> ...objects are equal if and only if the getTime method returns the same long value for both

Also, `Calendar`'s [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) won't work:

> The result is true if and only if the argument is a Calendar object of the same calendar system that represents the same time value

Simple solution: use the `Calendar`'s `getTime()` method, which returns a `Date` object which will readily compare with other dates using `equals()`, `after()`, and `before()`.

Or in code:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY, -1);
if(cal.getTime().equals(new Date())) { ... }
```

You could also instantiate another `Calendar` and use its `setTime()`, but that seems less efficient.

Comment: Thanks mate..this will work with some modifications here and there

Comment: @sys_debug I've edited my answer to address your secondary issue.  You'll probably want to instantiate `today` as `new Date()` as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are three JDBC types relating to time:

1. The **JDBC DATE** type represents a date consisting of day, month, and year. The corresponding SQL DATE type is defined in SQL-92, but it is implemented by only a subset of the major databases. Some databases offer alternative SQL types that support similar semantics.
2. The **JDBC TIME** type represents a time consisting of hours, minutes, and seconds. The corresponding SQL TIME type is defined in SQL-92, but it is implemented by only a subset of the major databases. As with DATE, some databases offer alternative SQL types that support similar semantics.
3. The **JDBC TIMESTAMP** type represents DATE plus TIME plus a nanosecond field. The corresponding SQL TIMESTAMP type is defined in SQL-92, but it is implemented by only a very small number of databases.

Because the standard Java class `java.util.Date` does not match any of these three JDBC date/time types exactly (it includes both DATE and TIME information but has no nanoseconds), JDBC defines three subclasses of `java.util.Date` to correspond to the SQL types. They are:

1. `java.sql.Date` for SQL DATE information. The hour, minute, second, and millisecond fields of the java.util.Date base class should be set to zero. If the number of milliseconds supplied to the java.sql.Date constructor is negative, the driver will compute the date as the number of milliseconds before January 1, 1970. Otherwise, the date is computed as the specified number of milliseconds after January 1, 1970.
2. `java.sql.Time` for SQL TIME information. The year, month, and day fields of the java.util.Date base class are set to 1970, January, and 1. This is the "zero" date in the Java epoch.
3. `java.sql.Timestamp` for SQL TIMESTAMP information. This class extends java.util.Date by adding a nanoseconds field.

All three of the JDBC time-related classes are subclasses of `java.util.Date`, and as such, they can be used where a `java.util.Date` is expected. For example, internationalization methods take a `java.util.Date` object as an argument, so they can be passed instances of any of the JDBC time-related classes.

A JDBC Timestamp object has its parent's date and time components and also a separate nanoseconds component. If a `java.sql.Timestamp` object is used where a `java.util.Date` object is expected, the nanoseconds component is lost.

However, since a `java.util.Date` object is stored with a precision of one millisecond, it is possible to maintain this degree of precision when converting a `java.sql.Timestamp` object to a `java.util.Date` object. This is done by converting the nanoseconds in the nanoseconds component to whole milliseconds (by dividing the number of nanoseconds by 1,000,000) and then adding the result to the `java.util.Date` object. Up to 999,999 nanoseconds may be lost in this conversion, but the resulting `java.util.Date` object will be accurate to within one millisecond.

The following code fragment is an example of converting a `java.sql.Timestamp` object to a `java.util.Date` object that is accurate to within one millisecond.

```
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(98724573287540L);
java.util.Date d;
d = new java.util.Date(t.getTime() + (t.getNanos() / 1000000));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `Date` type in your DB and you can have this directly as `Date`  instance in java